# How do I create this histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram for the wage variable

My code is

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
df=read.csv("/Users/takonyabadza/Desktop/Assign6data.csv")

select(df, wage)
W<-data.frame(df)
ggplot(W, aes(x = wage)) + geom_histogram()
logW<-log(df$wage)
ggplot(logW, aes(x= logW)) + geom_histogram()
```

As there is an error message on the last line that says-

Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Last line: I think it was typo: changed logW with W.

```
select(df, wage)
W<-data.frame(df)
ggplot(W, aes(x = wage)) + geom_histogram()
logW<-log(df$wage)
ggplot(W, aes(x= logW)) + geom_histogram()
```